# asp.net mvc - js file with server parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net mvc 3-4.0 and the question is how to pass a model value to a .js file. Sometimes i don't want to put too many jquery lines on my razor view page.

something likes

```
 $("#qcontent").load(
                    "@Url.Action("QuestionList", "TuongTac")",
                {
                    id: 1,
                    keywords: @Model.keyword
                    ....
                }
```

is it possible to make it work in a .js file ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way I've found to do this is to use `data-*` attributes.

In you Razor view:

```
<div id="qcontent" data-url="@Url.Action("QuestionList", "TuongTac")" data-keyword="@Model.keyword"></div>
```

Then in your external JavaScript file:

```
$("#qcontent").each(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var keyword = $(this).data('keyword');
    // ... 
});
```

Another option is to put the procedural JavaScript in an external file, and then dump out just the settings required in one hit in your Razor view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var qcontent.settings = @Json.Encode(new { url = Url.Action("QuestionList", "TuongTac"), keyword = @Model.Keyword });
</script>
```

and refer to it in your JavaScript file:

```
$("#qcontent").load(qcontent.settings.url, { id: 1, keyword: qcontent.settings.keyword });
```

The downside of this approach is that you are polluting the global namespace, so you'll want to be careful about namespacing.

Comment: To separate markup from your javascript data and simplify future refactorings it's better to use second option

Comment: Agreed, but there are certain situations where the second approach can get a lot more complicated (e.g. in custom editor or display templates which are used more than once per view)